# Setup Identity Server For Some Controllers And Not Others In .NET Core Web API

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

Suppose I had a new .NET Core 2.2 Web API Project with two controllers:

```
[ApiController]
public class AController : ControllerBase
{
}

[ApiController]
public class BController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

How can I setup the identity server so that authenticating with a reference token is necessary to hit endpoints on AController, but not BController?

Comment: Did the answer of Vidmantas work for you? Since you specifically mentioned 'a reference token'.

Answer (score 1):

Only add `[Authorize]` attribute to the controllers you need the users of your api to be authenticated for. Your other controllers won’t require token authentication that way.